# Equivalent of includes in wp7 sl?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, navigation

Navigating via Uris is a bit of a pain when you're designing a relatively big application in windows phone so I wrote a simple method like this:

```
void Navigate(string Frame)
{
       NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/{0}.xaml", 0), UriKind.Relative));
}
```

problem is, I want to include this code in all the PhoneApplicationPages which will be doing some navigation, but then I'm wondering if copy and paste is the only option, I would normally try to make my pages derive from a class which has the method and dervives from the base class but that will be another pain since the `PhoneApplicationPages` are partial classes. Could there be any other better way to achieve this or should I just copy and paste?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pull the method out into a static class and then pass the calling page as a reference;

```
public static class Navigator
{
    public static void Navigate(Page page, string frame)
    {
        page.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/{0}.xaml", frame), UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Then you simply call like this:

```
Navigator.Navigate(this, "NewPage");
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see any problem.

Create you base PhonePage:

```
public class PhoneApplicationPageBase : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public void Navigate()
        {

        }
        // Others methods
    }
```

in your pages derive from this:

```
public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPageBase
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

and in xaml too:

```
<my:PhoneApplicationPageBase
    x:Class="Views.Page1"
    ...>

</my:PhoneApplicationPageBase>
```

Or more. You can create extension-method.

```
 public static class Ext
    {
        public static void Navigate(this Page page, string view)
        {

        }
    }
```

then using `this.Navigate("Page2.xaml"`)

Comment: the problem with doing this is I also have to modify all the generated `g.i.cs` to derive from my custom class. And using an extension method will cause me to also write extension methods for all the classes no which is the same as copy and paste. No?

Comment: No. Extension methods will be available for all Phone objects.

Comment: About generated g.i.cs... You don't need change it yourself, IDE will do it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Roman that the process of deriving from a base page is tedious at worst: A few string replacements, and you're done.

I've got my own little mvvm toolkit, which includes a navigator service that (basically) maps uri's to page classes. On application start up you map page classes to uri's, and afterwards you can simply navigate to a view (uri) by specifying the class.

i.e., In the app constructor register the views:

```
    ViewNavigator.RegisterView<IMainView>(new Uri("/Pages/MainView.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

And from code you can navigate to a page by using

```
    ViewNavigator.Instance.NavigateTo<IMainView>();
```

The whole toolkit is more advanced than described here (support for parameters; including behaviours that allow you to the same through XAML), but I hope you get the general idea.

Comment: I don't really know how good the performance of this code will be but it doesn't look simple to me. Is the Instance reference static? When is ViewNavigator created? etc...

Comment: I didn't want to go into details, just to show the idea. In this case, ViewNavigator is a singleton. The "type-to-uri" resolving is a simple dictionary based operation, so that should be almost instant , and given the relative proportion of that operation in the whole process of navigating to a new page, practically zero. But more to the point, I wanted to show some idea of how to get rid of string constants everywhere in code, and replace them with a more type safe approach.